# AngularJS: Getting text from TD in directive attached via an attribute and raising event in controller $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I seem to have a small issue. I have created a directive and inserted the directive via an attribute on an existing DIV, see below.

```
<td my-directive>This Text I want to get hold of in my directive</td>
```

and the directive is displayed here. I did try playing around with element.parent() but this doesn't seem to work.

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.text(element.parent().text); // Doesn't work
      }
    };
  });
```

I want the TD to continue with its normal operation i.e. Displaying the text with the TD element. But its blank, so I thought about re-injecting it in the directive, but why is it blank?

Actually what I am trying to do is any part of the directive is clicked I want to do some internal stuff and then raise an event on the $scope which is shared by controller i.e.

```
      element.click(function(){
          //alert("direc clicked");
          scope.onClick()
      });
```

Not sure if I am doing this correct.

Anyone done this before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add `ng-transclude` in your template:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.text(element.parent().text); // Doesn't work
    }
  };
});
```

[source](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements)

Comment: Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <div ng-transclude="">

Comment: can you re-try with the `transclude: true` ?